Twilio play sound after digits input
I'd like to play an mp3 immediately after the user inputs their digits and #. But in my experience, the user has to wait for several seconds before the next sound plays. Is there a way to play a sound immediately after the user inputs digits and # (the sound will be something like "please wait").
After the gather, I expected the next sound to play immediately, but instead there is a delay of several seconds.
handleCall
const axios = require('axios');
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();


exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    console.log("Received incoming call");

    // Warm up the APIs
    try {
        const warmUpResponse = await axios.get('https://bobarke.com/_functions/warmup', { timeout: 60000 });
        console.log('Warm-up response:', warmUpResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during warm-up:', error);
    }

    // Create a <Gather> verb with a nested <Play> verb and a timeout of 3 seconds
    const gather = twiml.gather({
        action: '/processZip',
        method: 'POST',
        numDigits: 5,
        timeout: 3,
        finishOnKey: '#'
    });

    // Nest the <Play> verb within the <Gather> verb
    gather.play('https://hmp3.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/audio-d500e540-f05f-4e0d-8b25-323d15cc5aa6.mp3');


    console.log("Sending response to gather zip code");
    return callback(null, twiml);
};



processZip
const axios = require('axios');
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

twiml.play('https://hmp3.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/audio-6f45b4e0-1837-4b43-a229-3cf94d23eac1.mp3');

exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    console.log("Received zip code input");

    const zipCode = event.Digits;
    console.log("Digits received:", zipCode);

    if (!zipCode) {
        console.error("No zip code provided");
        twiml.say("Invalid input. Please try again.");
        return callback(null, twiml);
    }

    try {
        console.log("Fetching weather audio for zip code:", zipCode);
        const response = await axios.post('https://bobarke.com/_functions/processZip', null, {
            params: { Digits: zipCode },
            timeout: 60000 // Set timeout to 60 seconds
        });

        const audioUrl = response.data.audioUrl;
        console.log("Audio URL received:", audioUrl);

        if (!audioUrl) {
            console.error("No audio URL received from the response");
            twiml.say("Error retrieving weather forecast. Please try again later.");
            return callback(null, twiml);
        }

        // Use the <Play> verb to play the MP3 file directly
        twiml.play(audioUrl);
        console.log("Playing audio");
        
        twiml.pause({ length: 0.5 });
        
        twiml.play('https://hmp3.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/audio-e3218baf-c1b6-49ed-8734-87d3c3316eae.mp3');

        return callback(null, twiml);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
            console.error("Request timed out:", error);
            twiml.say("The request took too long. Please try again later.");
        } else {
            console.error("Error fetching weather audio:", error);
            twiml.say("Error retrieving weather forecast. Please try again later.");
        }

        return callback(null, twiml);
    }
};



All functions in Twilio must adhere to a maximum execution time of up to 3 seconds for everything to work perfectly well. Your problem might be exactly there.
